# When compiling,I write " gcc -g -Wall dene2 dene2.c", then gcc emits some trace

Tags: c, gcc

When I compile my code,I write `gcc -g -Wall dene2 dene2.c` in the console. Then gcc emits some text on the screen. I don't understand what this output means (I couldn't think of a meaningful title for that reason, sorry).

I have tried Google searching but haven't had any luck.

I'm not asking for a detailed examination of all of the output below. Just show me "how to catch fish".

```
dene2: In function `_start':
    /build/buildd/eglibc-2.10.1/csu/../sysdeps/i386/elf/start.S:65: multiple 
       definition of `_start'
   /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/crt1.o:/build/buildd/eglibc-2.10.1
      /csu/../sysdeps/i386/elf/start.S:65: first defined here
dene2:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_fp_hw'
   /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.rodata+0x0): first 
     defined here
dene2: In function `_fini':
   (.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
   /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined 
      here
dene2:(.rodata+0x4): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
   /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first 
     defined here
dene2: In function `__data_start':
 (.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
   /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined 
     here
dene2: In function `__data_start':
 (.data+0x4): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
  /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
dene2: In function `_init':
 (.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
  /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined 
       here
  /tmp/ccMlGkkV.o: In function `main':
  /home/fatih/Desktop/dene2.c:5: multiple definition of `main'
dene2:(.text+0xb4): first defined here
  /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/crtend.o:(.dtors+0x0): multiple definition of 
     `__DTOR_END__'
dene2:(.dtors+0x4): first defined here
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you probably want a `-o` in that command line:

```
gcc -g -Wall -o dene2 dene2.c
```

What you have there without the -o is trying to link `dene2` with the result of compiling `dene2.c`.  `dene2` is probably left over in your directory from previous build attempt.  That's why you're seeing all the duplicate symbol errors.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the -o in your compile line.

```
gcc -g -Wall -o dene2 dene2.c
```

The linker is trying to link your executable together with the source code you're current compiling, resulting in multiple definitions.